# Django ORM - select_related and order_by with foreign keys

Tags: django, foreign-keys, sql-order-by, django-select-related

I have a simple music schema: Artist, Release, Track, and Song.  The first 3 are all logical constructs while the fourth (Song) is a specific instance of an (Artist, Release, Track) as an mp3, wav, ogg, whatever.

I am having trouble generating an ordered list of the Songs in the database.  The catch is that both `Track` and `Release` have an `Artist`.  While `Song.Track.Artist` is always the performer name, `Song.Track.Release.Artist` may either be a performer name or "Various Artists" for compilations.  I want to be able to sort by one or the other, and I can't figure out the correct way to make this work.

Here's my schema:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Release(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    track_number = models.IntegerField('Position of the track on its release')
    length = models.IntegerField('Length of the song in seconds')
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release)

class Song(models.Model):
    bitrate = models.IntegerField('Bitrate of the song in kbps')
    location = models.CharField('Permanent storage location of the file', max_length=1024)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track)
```

My query should be fairly simple; filter for all songs owned by a specific user, and then sort them by either `Song.Track.Artist.name` or `Song.Track.Release.Artist.name`.  Here's my code inside a view, which is sorting by `Song.Track.Artist.name`:

```
songs = Song.objects.filter(owner=request.user).select_related('track__artist', 'track__release', 'track__release__artist').order_by('player_artist.name')
```

I can't get `order_by` to work unless I use `tblname.colname`.  I took a look at the underlying query object's `as_sql` method, which indicates that when the inner join is made to get `Song.Track.Release.Artist` the temporary name `T6` is used for the `Artist` table since an inner join was already done on this same table to get `Song.Track.Artist`:

```
>>> songs = Song.objects.filter(owner=request.user).select_related('track__artist', 'track__release', 'track__release__artist').order_by('T6.name')
>>> print songs.query.as_sql()
('SELECT "player_song"."id", "player_song"."bitrate", "player_song"."location", 
  "player_song"."owner_id", "player_song"."track_id", "player_track"."id", 
  "player_track"."name", "player_track"."track_number", "player_track"."length", 
  "player_track"."artist_id", "player_track"."release_id", "player_artist"."id", 
  "player_artist"."name", "player_release"."id", "player_release"."name", 
  "player_release"."artist_id", T6."id", T6."name" FROM "player_song" INNER JOIN 
  "player_track" ON ("player_song"."track_id" = "player_track"."id") INNER JOIN 
  "player_artist" ON ("player_track"."artist_id" = "player_artist"."id") INNER JOIN 
  "player_release" ON ("player_track"."release_id" = "player_release"."id") INNER JOIN 
  "player_artist" T6 ON ("player_release"."artist_id" = T6."id") WHERE 
  "player_song"."owner_id" = %s  ORDER BY T6.name ASC', (1,))
```

When I put this as the table name in `order_by` it does work (see example output above), but this seems entirely non-portable.  Surely there's a better way to do this!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 27):

I'm afraid I really can't understand what your question is.

A couple of corrections: `select_related` has nothing to do with ordering (it doesn't change the queryset at all, just follows joins to get related objects and cache them); and to order by a field in a related model you use the double-underscore notation, not dotted. For example:

```
Song.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('track__artist__name')
```

But in your example, you use 'player_artist', which doesn't seem to be a field anywhere in your model. And I don't understand your reference to portability.